# value not persist in hidden field

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

```
   int APP_TIME_SLOT = 5;    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           SetTimeSlot();
        } 



  private void SetTimeSlot()
   {
    SqlCommand objSqlCommand = null;
    strSQL = @"SELECT Time_Slot";

    objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, SqlConnectionObject);        

    string timeSlot = Convert.ToString(objSqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(objSqlCommand));
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeSlot))
     {
        APP_TIME_SLOT = Convert.ToInt32(timeSlot);
     }
    //SET TIMESLOT.READ ON CLIENT SIDE.     
    hidTimeSlot.Value = Convert.ToString(APP_TIME_SLOT);
   }
```

//javascript code

```
$("#contentPlaceHolderMain_btnFixAppointment").live('click', function (e)
{
  alert(document.getElementById('<%=hidTimeSlot.ClientID %>').value)
}
```

// i have to read timeslot value in client side.
but always getting me default value that is 5
i dont know whats wrong with my code.

Comment: You don't have a record in the table "Modality_Master" where the field "Modality_ID" is equal to the selected value of the drop down list "ddlModalityList". This got nothing to do with hidden field.

Comment: I am getting timeSlot value whatever in database but when i read on client side it gives me default value

Comment: You say that when you view the HTML source of the page you see value different than 5 in the hidden field?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="pageMain$contentPlaceHolderMain$hidTimeSlot" id="contentPlaceHolderMain_hidTimeSlot" value="5" />

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988060/value-not-persist-in-hidden-field?noredirect=1#comment26299366_17988060

Comment: showing me default value in view source also

Comment: Are there *any* places where you set the value for that HiddenField as well?
Maybe in a later stage of the page lifecycle?

Comment: no in only one place SetTimeSlot() function nothing else

Comment: Check your DropDownlist also. Show the markup of your dropdownlist and the function you are calling if you set the AutoPostback to true.

Answer (score 0):

write hidTimeSlot.Value = Convert.ToString(APP_TIME_SLOT);
inside the if statement...